# Making a python program wait until Twisted deferred returns a value

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

I have a program that fetches info from other pages and parses them using BeautifulSoup and Twisted's getPage. Later on in the program I print info that the deferred process creates. Currently my program tries to print it before the differed returns the info. How can I make it wait?

```
def twisAmaz(contents): #This parses the page (amazon api xml file)
    stonesoup = BeautifulStoneSoup(contents)
    if stonesoup.find("mediumimage") == None:
       imageurl.append("/images/notfound.png")
    else:
      imageurl.append(stonesoup.find("mediumimage").url.contents[0])

    usedPdata = stonesoup.find("lowestusedprice")
    newPdata = stonesoup.find("lowestnewprice")
    titledata = stonesoup.find("title")
    reviewdata = stonesoup.find("editorialreview")

    if stonesoup.find("asin") != None:
        asin.append(stonesoup.find("asin").contents[0])
    else:
        asin.append("None")
    reactor.stop()


deferred = dict()
for tmpISBN in isbn:  #Go through ISBN numbers and get Amazon API information for each
    deferred[(tmpISBN)] = getPage(fetchInfo(tmpISBN))
    deferred[(tmpISBN)].addCallback(twisAmaz)
    reactor.run()

.....print info on each ISBN
```

Comment: are you really using 1 space for indentation...

Comment: That was a formatting issue on here, the actual code uses tab

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What it seems like is you're trying to make/run multiple reactors. Everything gets attached to the *same* reactor. Here's how to use a [`DeferredList`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#auto8) to wait for all of your callbacks to finish.

Also note that `twisAmaz` returns a value. That value is passed through the `callbacks` `DeferredList` and comes out as `value`. Since a `DeferredList` keeps the order of the things that are put into it, you can cross-reference the index of the results with the index of your ISBNs.

```
from twisted.internet import defer

def twisAmazon(contents):
    stonesoup = BeautifulStoneSoup(contents)
    ret = {}
    if stonesoup.find("mediumimage") is None:
        ret['imageurl'] = "/images/notfound.png"
    else:
        ret['imageurl'] = stonesoup.find("mediumimage").url.contents[0]
    ret['usedPdata'] = stonesoup.find("lowestusedprice")
    ret['newPdata'] = stonesoup.find("lowestnewprice")
    ret['titledata'] = stonesoup.find("title")
    ret['reviewdata'] = stonesoup.find("editorialreview")
    if stonesoup.find("asin") is not None:
        ret['asin'] = stonesoup.find("asin").contents[0]
    else:
        ret['asin'] = 'None'
    return ret

callbacks = []
for tmpISBN in isbn:  #Go through ISBN numbers and get Amazon API information for each
    callbacks.append(getPage(fetchInfo(tmpISBN)).addCallback(twisAmazon))

def printResult(result):
    for e, (success, value) in enumerate(result):
        print ('[%r]:' % isbn[e]),
        if success:
            print 'Success:', value
        else:
            print 'Failure:', value.getErrorMessage()

callbacks = defer.DeferredList(callbacks)
callbacks.addCallback(printResult)

reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 4):

Another cool way to do this is with @defer.inlineCallbacks. It lets you write asynchronous code like a regular sequential function: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.html#inlineCallbacks

Answer (score 2):

First, you shouldn't put a reactor.stop() in your deferred method, as it kills everything.

Now, in Twisted, "Waiting" is not allowed. To print results of you callback, just add another callback after the first one.

Comment: Thanks, Luc! May I ask where the reactor.stop() should go?

Comment: When I said to not put a reactor.stop(), I meant to not put it in that first deferred code, as it would stop everything.
So yo should put it in the last deferred (the one that print the results) where you're sure you want to stop your program.
Just a note: you should use addCallbacks(method1,error_method) to catch to potential errors.

Comment: Look at the tutorial about deferred on http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/deferredindepth.html, especially the section named 'Callbacks can return deferreds'.

Comment: Okay, thanks! And the only issue I have now is that I'm accessing several sites and trying to print the data in a specific order, so if I have a function for each site then it might print them out of order...